# TLP383 ltspice XVII model not working because of encryption?

Tags: ltspice, model

I tried to test the model of the TLP383 in ltspice which I downloaded from toshiba. [TLP383](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/eu/semiconductor/product/optoelectronics/detail.TLP383.html)

I added it as I always did with my models downloaded from the internet.
But this time ltspice gives me the error:

> Unknown SPICE device type "1" in "17f62b..."

So I wanted to ask if somebody also experienced something like this or if anybody got a working model of the TLP383?

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: It's a PSPICE model not an LTSPICE model. Compatibility between them may be limited and may not extend to encrypted models, as "* Operation of this model has been verified only on the OrCAD." suggests.

Comment: Yeah I had some PSPICE models which I still could even use with LTSPICE. This was my first with a encrypted model. I thought that "Operation of this model has been verified only on the OrCAD" means that it could also work with other SPICE programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open a Pspice model in LTspice. I don't see any SPICE models other than the Pspice one in the linked site.

---

To elaborate, yes it's true that SPICE is SPICE and LTspice is perfectly fine with unencrypted models made in Pspice, but every Pspice model I've ever encountered has been encrypted. As is the case with this one--note how line 14 in the .lib reads `**$ENCRYPTED_LIB`.

Comment: LTspice is PSpice compatible, unless the model is encrypted (not by LTspice).

Comment: Well, yes, SPICE is SPICE, but every model I've ever seen that calls itself a "Pspice model" has been encrypted.

Comment: There are plenty Pspice models that aren't encrypted, but maybe not in this case (the page doesn't open for me). It's easy to open it up with a text editor and if it says "encrypted" (and it's not by LTspice), then it's a clear no.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for this fast answers! Now I learned something new again.

Comment: I will try to find a model which I can use as a alternative for the TLP383 to use in ltspice.

Comment: SPICE is SPICE only to a certain extent. While PSPICE and LTSPICE may be largely compatible, other SPICEs (NGSPICE and probably HSPICE, possibly TI TINA) have significant syntactic and other incompatibilities.